# How to receive bytes when video is recording

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

i am developing iphone video app,in that i want to get bytes occupied in disk when user is recording the video itself  .

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;
```

this method is called after user is finished picking.is there any method

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
 NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0); 
 NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NSData *data = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
```

Comment: but i want that to be happen when video is recording not when - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info; delegate method it should be written and more over UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata will only work for still images not for video capturing.